# Floating divs issue

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `<div>` containing multiple child `<div>`. I need to float the child `<div>` to left.The issue is my parent `<div>` is not expanding properly  and the last child `<div>` is going below the other child `<div>`.
I tried setting parent `<div>` css to `overflow:hidden; clear:both;` but none of them worked.
Please let me know any possible solutions

**CSS:**

```
.rightpanel 
{
   width:80%;
   float:right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<DIV id="div_rightPanel" class="rightpanel">
   <DIV style="WIDTH: 100%">
      <DIV style="POSITION: relative; TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 93px; FONT-FAMILY: calibri; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 50px; FONT-SIZE: small" id="div_2009" class="year">
         2009
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 0px" id="div_2009_2" class="quarter">Q2</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 31px" id="div_2009_3" class="quarter">Q3</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 62px" id="div_2009_4" class="quarter">Q4</DIV>
      </DIV>
      <DIV style="POSITION: relative; TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 124px; FONT-FAMILY: calibri; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 50px; FONT-SIZE: small" id="div_2010" class="year">
         2010
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 0px" id="div_2010_1" class="quarter">Q1</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 31px" id="div_2010_2" class="quarter">Q2</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 62px" id="div_2010_3" class="quarter">Q3</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 93px" id="div_2010_4" class="quarter">Q4</DIV>
      </DIV>
      <DIV style="POSITION: relative; TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 124px; FONT-FAMILY: calibri; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 50px; FONT-SIZE: small" id="div_2011" class="year">
         2011
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 0px" id="div_2011_1" class="quarter">Q1</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 31px" id="div_2011_2" class="quarter">Q2</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 62px" id="div_2011_3" class="quarter">Q3</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 93px" id="div_2011_4" class="quarter">Q4</DIV>
      </DIV>
      <DIV style="POSITION: relative; TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 124px; FONT-FAMILY: calibri; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 50px; FONT-SIZE: small" id="div_2012" class="year">
         2012
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 0px" id="div_2012_1" class="quarter">Q1</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 31px" id="div_2012_2" class="quarter">Q2</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 62px" id="div_2012_3" class="quarter">Q3</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 93px" id="div_2012_4" class="quarter">Q4</DIV>
      </DIV>
      <DIV style="POSITION: relative; TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 124px; FONT-FAMILY: calibri; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 50px; FONT-SIZE: small" id="div_2013" class="year">
         2013
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 0px" id="div_2013_1" class="quarter">Q1</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 31px" id="div_2013_2" class="quarter">Q2</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 62px" id="div_2013_3" class="quarter">Q3</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 93px" id="div_2013_4" class="quarter">Q4</DIV>
      </DIV>
      <DIV style="POSITION: relative; TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 62px; FONT-FAMILY: calibri; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 50px; FONT-SIZE: small" id="div_2014" class="year">
         2014
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 0px" id="div_2014_1" class="quarter">Q1</DIV>
         <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 31px; BOTTOM: 0px; FLOAT: left; HEIGHT: 25px; LEFT: 31px" id="div_2014_2" class="quarter">Q2</DIV>
      </DIV>
   </DIV>
</DIV> '
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTML and CSS or a demo on jsFiddle what you're currently trying? We need a good basis to start on, even if it's some images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article about [HTML positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).

You are using `position: absolute` and `float: left` for one block which is contradictory.

For positioning your inner blocks inside some container block, you can use:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

And stylesheet:

```
.container
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.inner
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ravi see the basic concept is if we want to achieve your desire result so we can get easily no need to use `positioning` as you used in your code we can easily achieve via `floating`

I mentioning below the basic concept idea how you can get your desired result....

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
border:3px solid blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.child {
width:25%;
height:20px;
float:left;
background:green;
}
.child:nth-child(2n) {
background:red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://tinkerbin.com/7OLxccU9)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a clearing element.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">content</div>
  <div class="child">content</div>
  <div class="clear"><!--no content--></div>
</div>
```

The div with a class of clear can be used as way to cause your parent to flow back the way you would expect. place it at the end of all floated elements and just before the closing tag of the parent. Then just add some css to the clear class like this.

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
```

Take note that if you are using this in a layout that also uses floats to create it's column it may break it by causing other columns to be pushed below the element doing the clearing. To fix this you will have to wrap the parent in a container div and float the container which will cause the other columns to not be affected by the float since clears do not extend outside of floated parents.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The above answer will work.. I have found that using the overflow:hidden can cause strange issues with complex layouts though.